# LINQ to SQL. ChangeConflictException: MemberConflicts.Count = 0

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm using LINQ to SQL on data layer of my application. I've got strange "type" of error on submit changes. Here is a part of my code:

```
try
{
    dataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict);
}
catch (ChangeConflictException)
{
    foreach (ObjectChangeConflict conflict in dataContext.ChangeConflicts)
    {
        foreach(MemberChangeConflict memberConflict in conflict.MemberConflicts)
        {
            memberConflict.Resolve(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues);
        }   
    }
}
```

It always works fine and all conflicts resolved succesfully. But now I've got a conflict where conflict.MemberConflicts = 0. ChangeConflictException have no information about conflict, Inner Exception is null. So I haven't idea why I've got this conflict and what I have to do with it. 
This isn't help too:

```
conflict.Resolve(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues);
```

Only thing, that I've noticed, this is happens when I try to delete entity from database. But this code is works for delete in the other situations.
I understand that it's very few information about my problem, but maybe someone can give me advice what I need to check?

Comment: why not check the value on your exception? `catch (ChangeConflictException ex)`

Comment: Yep, of course, I check an exception, but exception message just says: "1 of X updates failed." Inner exception is null. Here is an image [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13471945/so_exception_error_01.png)

Comment: What kind of changes were you submitting? Inserts? Updates? Deletes? Or a combination (and if so, what combination) ?

Comment: Combination of updates and deletes. Exception throws on delete (conflict.Object contains entity which must be deleted from the database on this submit).

Comment: As said by @Jonesy, use the info supplied in the exception iow `ex`.

Comment: Yep, but there no useful info. Yes, I see the conflict object and I see exception message: "1 of X updates failed". But when I exam the object I can't see any special in it. And anyway, I'll try to delete this object (it's not an insert or update operation).

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, but this is not a good solution. Just separate updates and deletes in two different submit changes. First I made all updates, then deletes. And it works. But I still have no idea, why this won't work together in one submit.